# Error with API from R using JSON (Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : SSL connect error)

Tags: r, json, rest, api

I am trying to access data from this link (https://db.cilaboratory.org:8080/naemp/sites),

I keep getting this error...

```
"Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : SSL connect error". 

    > sites <- fromJSON('https://db.cilaboratory.org:8080/naemp/sites')
    Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : SSL connect error
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is no https version of the website, use the http version instead

```
(sites <- jsonlite::fromJSON('http://db.cilaboratory.org:8080/naemp/sites'))
```

Comment: I get this new error! :( > sites <- fromJSON('http://db.cilaboratory.org:8080/naemp/sites/fishID')
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 400.

Comment: which website are you trying to access? http://db.cilaboratory.org:8080/naemp/sites or http://db.cilaboratory.org:8080/naemp/sites/fishID? your OP was http://db.cilaboratory.org:8080/naemp/sites. Are you able to open the new link in a web browser? if not, then the site does not exist in the first place

Answer (score 0):

For this:
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_UNTRUSTED_ROOT (0x80090325) - La cadena de certificación fue emitida por una entidad en la que no se confía.

I used ->

```
require(jsonlite)

url<-jsonlite::fromJSON("http://192.25.5.31:8080/api-rest/rest/comercial/lotes-libres?proyecto=xxx")
```

for connect is important, write "http" and write the port (in this case "8080").

then you can to read the data url